# Printing and formatting results in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

My problem is that I want to print only this results with '1', not '-1', but when I use `find()` I just get '1' or '-1'. I know that is working but is there any function to print only this with '1', not number but whole line?

```
import requests
import bs4

def links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    tmp = soup.find_all('a')

    for links in tmp:
        print(links.get('href'),  links.get('href').find("torrent_download"))


url="http://extratorrent.cc"
print(links(url))
```

Sample of results:

```
/category/23/zzz.html -1

/torrent_download/4188694/zzz.torrent 1

/torrent/4188694/zzz.html#comments -1

/torrent_download/4188710/zzz.torrent 1
```

Results that I want:

```
/torrent_download/4188710/zzz.torrent 1
/torrent_download/4188694/zzz.torrent 1
```

Comment: I think adding the result you want would be easier to understand

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham
Ok, I added the result which I want get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the get.find before you print:

```
for links in tmp:
    get  =  links.get('href').find("torrent_download")
    if get != -1:
        print(links.get('href'),  get)
```

Comment: Great, Thank You very much. This is what I wanted to achieve :)